# How to save Firebase DataSnapshot object to shared Preferences?

Tags: android, serialization, firebase, sharedpreferences, snapshot

I am trying to save a Firebase DataSnapshot object to sharedpreferences.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460443/having-problems-designing-sign-in-sign-up-logic-with-firebase-android) in which I have devised a method that involves doing this.

...

What I have tried so far:

1. Using [Gson.Json method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18463758/5717640).  RESULT: Doesn't seem to work... I don't think the DataSnapshot class is a "POJO" type class... at least not one that will work with gson.
2. Using this method:

   private static String toString( Serializable o ) throws IOException {
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( baos );
   oos.writeObject( o );
   oos.close();
   return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
   }

RESULT: Doesn't work... I don't think that the DataSnapshot class is 'Serializable'.

I thought of another method -- Just save DataSnapshot.toString() into Sharedpreferences... but then how do you get it back out again?  You can't do:

```
DataSnapshot snapshot = new DataSnapshot().fromString([string from sharedprefs])
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You're not supposed to save big chunks of **data** in sharedpreferences

Comment: How do you know how big it is, have you seen my database?  How big is too big?

Comment: this is bad approach to store datasnapshot in shared preference and this is technically not phisible

Comment: Regardless of the size of the data, my 'advice' still stands. I would suggest you look for an alternative

Comment: Firebase supports directly enablePersistenceStorage for offline support

Comment: Well... if either of you could look deeper into the post I referred to that explains why I'm trying to do this, and suggest a better design I would be much obliged.

Comment: Thankyou Vishal... I'm going to study that next I think that might hold the solution.

Comment: You can make a model class acting as a adapter between DataSnapshot and then you can use Gson to save it.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39435730/6561141). It might help.

Comment: That's the same as"  "What I have tried so far:

1) Using Gson.Json method. RESULT: Doesn't seem to work... I don't think the DataSnapshot class is a "POJO" type class... at least not one that will work with gson."

Comment: Thanks though... I think I'm going to try a different approach anyway... looks like "callback hell" is my only choice considering my present knowledge and abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same issue. I wanted to save Datasnapshot inside SharedPreferences and my json data was bit complicated. So I wrote below code.

//To save to sharedpreference

```
 public void setAppLanguageDataSnapshot(DataSnapshot mDataSnapshot) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(mDataSnapshot.getValue());
        StorageUtils.getInstance(context).setString(AppConstants.SharedPrefConstants.APP_CONTENT, json);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

//To get data as JSON object.

```
 String data = StorageUtils.getInstance(context).getString(AppConstants.SharedPrefConstants.APP_CONTENT);
    String value = "";
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data)) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```