# Firebase Realtime Database & Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have recently adopted Firebase for my Backend work. Using Firebase I want to store all the user data like username, phone number, etc to Firebase in the same `RegisterActivity` and not just Email & Password. How can I achieve this ?

My `RegisterActivity` will only appear at the time of installation. When user have register to my app, I am destroying the activity. So, there is no instance of `RegisterActivity` further.

`RegisterActivity - onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    initialization();
    underlineText();    //Underlining Text in App

    userObj = new User();
    userObj.setName(NAME);
    userObj.setEMAIL(EMAIL);
    userObj.setPHONE(PHN);

    animShake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake);     //Animation

    vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);    //Vibration

    reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submitForm();   //Registration Click Listener
        }
    });

    skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            skipRegistrationSection();  //Skip Click Listener
        }
    });

    runAtInstallation();
}
```

`submitform()`:

```
private void submitForm() {

    if (!checkName()) {
        name.setAnimation(animShake);
        name.startAnimation(animShake);
        vib.vibrate(60);
        return;
    }
    if (!checkEmail()) {
        email.setAnimation(animShake);
        email.startAnimation(animShake);
        vib.vibrate(60);
        return;
    }
    if (!checkPhone()) {
        phone.setAnimation(animShake);
        phone.startAnimation(animShake);
        vib.vibrate(60);
        return;
    }
    if (!checkPassword()) {
        password.setAnimation(animShake);
        password.startAnimation(animShake);
        vib.vibrate(60);
        return;
    }
    if (!checkConfirmPassword()) {
        confirmPassword.setAnimation(animShake);
        confirmPassword.startAnimation(animShake);
        vib.vibrate(60);
        return;
    }

    nameLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
    emailLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
    phoneLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
    passwordLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
    confirmPasswordLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);

    NAME = name.getText().toString().trim();
    EMAIL = email.getText().toString().trim();
    PHN = phone.getText().toString().trim();
    PASSWORD = password.getText().toString();

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    authUser();     //authenticating  User via Email & Password

}
```

`authUser()`:

```
private void authUser() {

    mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(EMAIL, PASSWORD).addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(task.getException().getMessage())
                        .setTitle("Error")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

`runAtInstallation`:

```
private void runAtInstallation() {

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)) {

        Intent act = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        act.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        act.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(act);
        finish();
    } else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
        ed.commit();
    }
}
```

I want to save name,email,& phone in the firebase database during registration and to destroy the activity after that.

Comment: We need more information to help you. For example show us your code in the `RegisterActivity` and explain exactly what the problem is and what you are having trouble with.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I have edited my query. Please have a look !! Thank U

Comment: Are You want to add like profile pic, phone number  or etc to authenticated user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460443/having-problems-designing-sign-in-sign-up-logic-with-firebase-android) right now.  The thing is, sign-IN (authentication) and sign-UP (registration) are two different things.

What I have done is have two separate activities, signIN... and signUP (register).

Once the user is signed up (email and password), they will have a unique userID known to Firebase.

Next, they go to the registration activity, so when you "upload" all the data from the editTexts in this activity, you can upload them to a node (key... index) in your database that matches the userID... so your data in your database looks like:

\ mydatabase \ users \ [uniqueID] \

If you combine both activies (authentication and registration) into one... with many fields, "email, password, name, phonenumber, etc." all in one activity, then you're going to still need to make a separate signIN only activity for the next time they run the app with an expired session.  I think it's much simpler to do two separate activites.

Comment: I have two separate activities for sign-in  & sign-up. But in the sign-up i want to save the username,email,& phone in the database and the direct the user to the `MainActivity`.

Comment: In your question there are 3 things, sign-in, sign-up, register. so without sign-up, user cannot sign-in and register is completely a different thing. But more or less we both have the same problem.

Comment: I think if @XaverKapeller takes a look he will have a much better answer than I can give you... even though I do describe some possible solutions in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I have one activity and I simply try to register right away regardless if the user exists or not and then if the error is due to the email existing already I sign the user in instead of registering them.

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {                       
if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
// login user
}
else {
// handle error
}
}    
else {
// register user
}
}
```

Comment: But then they would have filled out all those registration forms for no reason, no?  And they would also be confused and think their account has been deleted.

Comment: For me it is a simple email and password login, therefore they do not need to fill out a huge registration form again when logging in.

Answer (score 0):

You can add user profile information and other details like

For update profile

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
        .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

For more details to manage user details please refer this link [Firebase manage user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)